# Were Morgan Freeman's scenes filmed separately and spliced in later?

Tags: production, film-techniques, editing, now-you-see-me-2

In "Now You See Me 2", most (all?) of the scenes with Morgan Freeman look like they were filmed separately with standings playing the other actors.

This is especially obvious in the scenes involving Freeman and Mark Ruffalo.  Whenever you can see one character's face, the other is shown only from behind.

It's like the two actors filmed their lines at different times and the results were edited together to make a conversation.

Perhaps the two actors never even met each other during the filming of this movie.

If this is actually what happened, what was the reason for it?

Comment: You might find this question on Sci Fi SE interesting too: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146432/was-bill-murray-actually-in-the-room-with-the-2016-ghostbusters

Comment: @Longshanks, yes, I get the same feeling with that scene as I did with the Freeman-in-prison scenes.  Coincidentally, neither Freeman nor Murray wanted to reprise their roles.  Perhaps he too gave them only one day of shooting, and they shot a lot of his dialog one-sided to fit it in.

Answer (score 1):

### No...

They clearly acted together...here's one example

[image]

Now, it's possible that **some** scenes (or coverage) were filmed using stand-ins. Morgan Freeman is not a young man and you don't necessarily need him to actually be in shot when all you are doing is actually shooting the back of his head.